# Is it normal that migration from ASP.NET Core 2.2 to 3.0 (3.1 in real) creates launchSettings.json files for all libraries

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-3.0, asp.net-core-3.1

I am trying to migrate my ASP.NET Core 2.2 project to 3.1. In order to successful build I need to add:

```
<!-- Avoid: Program does not contain a static 'Main' method suitable for an entry point -->
<OutputType>Library</OutputType>
```

to `PropertyGroup` for all my libraries.

I don't know if this is related, but I notice that re-building my application creates `launchSettings.json` for every (15) `.NET Core` class library.

Is this normal? I just said in `.csproj` that this is library and launchSetting file is created.

Comment: why do you need to add <OutputType>Library</OutputType>? i've never needed to do that in my netstandard libraries.

Comment: Maybe this `<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">` force to set this. Otherwise I get compile error.

Comment: Maybe your library isn't a library? in my netstandard libraries i have Microsoft.NET.Sdk (without the web. the web one is used in the main application project only). check this one out : https://andrewlock.net/converting-a-netstandard-2-library-to-netcore-3/